# Do I need the latest version of Xcode to submit apps to the app store?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm currently running Xcode version 3.2.5 on Snow Leopard (10.6.6). That means I can run applications on the simulator up to iOS 4.2.

Does it matter if I submit an app for approval with an out-of-date version of Xcode? Will devices running iOS 4.2.1 or greater be able to install my app from the app store?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple's submission policies, not programming.

Answer (score 3):

As of last week, Apple accepted submissions linked against iOS SDK 4.3. Anything below will not be accepted.
Within a foreseeable future, Apple will move on to accept submissions linked against iOS SDK 5 only (and so on).

Within your project/build-settings, you can however always select a minimal (target) iOS version. Lets say you build against iOS 5, then you can still select iOS 4.2 as the lowest version that would be compatible with your app. Anything from iOS 4.2 up to iOS 5 will then be accepted (and should be tested with on your side). Actually, when trying to target 4.2, there will be another factor you would have to tackle: ARMV6. For that, see various other questions and answers here on StackOverflow. *Note* that iOS 4.2.1 was the last version available for users of the ARMV6 based hardware (e.g. iPhone 3G).

Or in other words, the Xcode version is secondary. The important part is the iOS SDK you link against.

Comment: really helpful information, im gonna install xcode 4 and set a minimal target of ios 4.2 , thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apple don't care what version of Xcode you use, but they do expect you to deploy builds built against the latest SDK.

If your app is not built against the iOS5 SDK, there is a fairly good chance that it will be rejected.

Why not just install Xcode 4 in a separate directory on your Mac? Then you can still test for older SDKs but will be able to build against the latest SDK.

Comment: "Apple don't care what version of Xcode you use, but they do expect you to deploy builds built against the latest SDK." I thought the only way to change your SDK version was to change your version of XCode? Am I wrong?

Comment: Apple update Xcode more often than they update the SDK. For example Xcode 4.5.2 has the same SDK (6.0) as 4.5.1. It's fine to submit apps using Xcode 4.5.1, but it would not be advisable to submit apps build against the 5.0 SDK.

Comment: Incidentally, I think my original answer is not completely accurate: You can't submit apps using Xcode 4.6 beta even if you target the 6.0 SDK for example.