# Will the same iOS SDK have different behaviors using different Xcode versions

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sdk

At first my first question was: Will I be able to upload the the appStore using an old SDK. Looking at the apple [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1806/_index.html), and a stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143133/do-i-need-the-latest-version-of-xcode-to-submit-apps-to-the-app-store), I arrived to the conclusion that I can upload my application using an old SDK as long as it's in a reasonable amount of time since the new SDK has been released. I could not find the minimum required SDK for approval though. At that point in my research, I think that I can use an old SDK to submit my application. Am I in the wrong? How long should I expect the current latest Xcode 7 SDK to be supported ?

(I do know we should move to the latest SDK as soon as we can.)

My company is working on several iOS projects, and we are having a big patch soon for one of them (maybe in December). **We do not want to introduce new bugs**. We understand we must change the SDK, but at this point in time, it would be too much time consuming. Some of us would like to enjoy the latest version of Xcode for some native projects, which brings me to my second question. Right now if we have a bug free application using Xcode X (7), can we expect the same bug free application using Xcode X+1 (8) with the same SDK. Is this safe or would we take a risk?

Comment: can you just update Xcode on a single machine, make a copy/fork of the projects and check on the updated machine for new warnings/errors ?

Comment: usually you have until january

Comment: @Jef I could fork on different machines, but since I cannot run the automated testing (it doesn't cover the app 100% anyway), it would be difficult to ensure the entire app is bug free. rafaperez : Thanks, really appreciated. Is there somewhere I can find official times in the past, or or some Apple statistic about their timeline ?